# Can diff show numerical differences, with a threshold to not show them as differences?

Tags: diff, file-comparison, numeric-data

My diff shows some numerical differences between two log files. 
That means for example:

```
fileA: 

        Parameter            n (fill abs)
        /All_Data/Height     9830400

fileB: 

        Parameter            n (fill abs)
        /All_Data/Height     9830500
```

SO, if the `diff` command is executed between the files:

```
% diff fileA fileB
-> 
< /All_Data/Height     9830400
---
> /All_Data/Height     9830500
```

I would like to set a threshold in the diff command what is to say

1. display the difference if the discrepancy between the number is greater than `500`. So `9830400-9830500=100`. No differences should be displayed.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Where did you get an idea that `diff` will compute the arithmetic? i.e. that too floating point?

Comment: could your files contain more than one line? Are there always be only digits?

Comment: So if it is impossible to compile arithmetic with diff, the solution will be indeed more difficult.
@RomanPerekherst: 
My files contain more than one line. It actually contain table of values that will not be always exactly the same between the two files.... 
The difference are not only digits. It can also be alphabetical..

Comment: @VictorDoors: Can you state your expectation clearly?

Comment: I want to control the numerical differences between two log files. This is to say implement a threeshold. If the difference between the two numerical value is lower than x. Don't warn the operator with a difference....

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to control the numerical differences between two log files` ? does the file have content only a numerical value? you claimed the opposite in one of the earlier comments, that it could contain characters also?

Comment: there could be multiple differences between 2 files: one that fits the threshold, another - doesn't. How would you treat that?

Comment: You need to show your input and the expected output files, comprising the many scenarios you will be having. Your current example of 0.25 vs 0.5 is just not sufficient.

Comment: Is there a strict 1:1 mapping of data points in each file, so we can compare line 1 to line 1, line 2 to line 2, and so on? It wouldn't be difficult to put a script together that looped across the lines (`while read...`) and applied a simple floating point numerical comparison. Look at `read -u` to read from a named file descriptor.

Comment: `awk` will be your friend here. Not `diff`.

Comment: @pfnuesel: Can you detail a bit more... Does awk allow to get the value of one attribute in a log file and compare it with the value the attribute in the other file and for example substitute the value with a token like \__DATA__ if the difference between the values is lower than a threshold i.e 500? Then I know that the diff will not display differences. That could be a good solution. How would be the command? I modified the description to give a more accurate structure of the data in my log files

Comment: @VictorDoors I'm afraid I don't have the time right now. What you can do is accept the `spiff` answer, and ask a new one. Make sure to put the `awk` tag in the question.

Answer (score 6):

That's essentially what [**`spiff`**](http://www.math.utah.edu/cgi-bin/man2html.cgi?/usr/local/man/man1/spiff.1) did, and there have been a few others of the same sort (not as well known).  `spiff` was rather fragile (dumped core easily).

Comment: Related: [tre](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/), used for fuzzy matching.  Also fragile, to the point of being unusable.

Comment: Looks like it still lives at https://github.com/dontcallmedom/spiff at least

Comment: @Thomas Dickey: Thank you for your answer. 
However I am struggling to install spiff in SLES11. spiff uses the library lcurses and lcurses uses lua. In my case lcurses is complaining with really ugly lua source code errors.
Do you know other programs similar to spiff?

Comment: You've found a different **`spiff`**. Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428177/diff-tool-that-ignores-floating-point-formats-but-not-values-in-text)