# Is there a diff(1) that calculates deltas over numbers on each matching line?

Tags: diff

Is there any form of `diff` that detects matching lines, i.e., lines containing the same text, except for numerical values (decimal, octal, hexadecimal), and then calculates the delta for those numbers, outputting each matched line with the deltas?

It would need to determine the position of the numerical fields since they may not always be in the same position in some files (like the output of `netstat -s`, for example).

Ideally, the output format should be customizable (e.g., printing deltas at the beginning for easier sorting of results, etc).

I am sure I can write something, but why reinvent the wheel if it already exists?

Comment: This answers your question: [Can diff show numerical differences, with a threshold to not show them as differences?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369691/can-diff-show-numerical-differences-with-a-threshold-to-not-show-them-as-differ)

Comment: Kindly add some sample input and output. It could be that other tools are able to manage your problem, but one would need to see how things are sorted. Kindly define what you mean by "position": charachters, fields, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The only `diff` tools I've ever encountered consider differences line-by-line (usually with a "*delete this line, insert those lines*" type approach). This works well with the complementary `patch`.

The closest might be the interactive `vimdiff`, but even that doesn't really address the issue.

If you want to find lines that match, other than numeric values, I'd approach this by substituting all numeric values (according to some defined template) with, say `XXNUMBERXX` in both files for comparison and then using a standard `diff` tool